# 48 FPS Video and Pro Tools

Tags: pro-tools, video

A show that I'll be starting on soon is cutting picture with a 48 timecode base because the action sequences were all shot at 48 or 96 FPS, with the intention of projecting the finished project at 48 FPS, like the first Hobbit film.

Has anyone had to deal with a 48 FPS workflow in Pro Tools yet? I'm worried about conforms that involve odd-numbered frame changes that won't translate to a 23.98 TC environment in Pro Tools for one thing.

Thanks,
Paul

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just ask them to print you a 24 FPS version in every version they send you?  sort of like for a 3d film only receinving one "side" of the stereo image for the workprint.  Basically every other frame, I can't imagine much of a sync difference between 24 and 48.  quarter frames are high enough resolution for judging sync in my opinion, beyond that you're splitting hairs.  I've never loaded such framerates into PT, but I gather that you can and just set Timecode 2 to display 48 (even though the session main timecode runs 24).  I think 48 is an option for Timecode 2.

Comment: I'm going to try to get the 48 FPS picture with a 23.98 burn-in. Unfortunately, 48 FPS isn't a TC option either for the primary or secondary base. 

Another issue is that there will be a lot of gunshots in the picture and muzzle flashes may only be one frame long, so a 24 FPS picture could potentially lose some of that information.

Comment: maybe useful to find out how the editor worked on the film, my impression for 3D is that the editor works primarily with a 2D image so time critical cues still adhere to a 2D framerate?